# Help with putting footnote in the Section

Tags: sectioning, footnotes

I am trying put footnote in the section for the document with documentclass res.cls. I am using the following tex file but I am not getting the desired result. Basically I am not seeing any footnote. Here is the tex code:

```
\documentclass[margin]{res}
\begin{document}

\name{John Doe\\[12pt]} % the \\[12pt] adds a blank line after name

\address{{\bf Present Address}}
\begin{resume}
\section{EXAMS \protect\footnote{This is a footnote}}

\end{resume}
\end{document}
```

Please give some suggestions. Thanks

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) A tip: If you indent lines by 4 spaces, they'll be [marked as a code sample](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1192). You can also highlight the code and click the "code" button (with "{}" on it).

Comment: Thanks..For the time being I can use a workaround for this by using footnotemark and footnotetext. I just wanted to know if there is something more effective.

Comment: It would be better for you to edit your OP and add, as an PS, the remark you just said, so that the OP be more specific to your request.

Comment: @user27396: What do you mean by "more effective"?

Comment: i'm not familiar with the `res` document class, but it's not uncommon for some command arguments to be set in a "local group", and a footnote can't "escape" from such a group.  if grouping is involved here, then `\footnotemark` and `\footnotetext` is your only plausible alternative.

Comment: @werner: something like \footnote with options which does work for other document classes but not for res class.